# Android: AsyncTask needs a context to show an alert after leaving containing activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I have two activities, one of them calls an inner task of the form: private class AsyncTask, it calls the task and then finishes up, going to the other activity. The AsyncTask shows an alert dialog at some point, but most likely that the context, which is needed to create the alert, of the first activity is not the current context of the application, that is, not of the currently working activity. So when the dialog.show() called in the AsyncTask, the app crashes.

Any help there how to solve it?

I haven't posted any code because I think Its better if you just get the idea without understanding codes, I debugged the app and it really crashes after executing alert.show().

LogCat output:
`11-24 13:30:08.561: W/dalvikvm(2810): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cd69a8) 11-24 13:30:08.752: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0) 11-24 13:30:08.753: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0) 11-24 13:30:08.753: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0) 11-24 13:30:08.754: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)`

Comment: but showing logcat will be a good thing...

Comment: 11-24 13:30:08.561: W/dalvikvm(2810): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41cd69a8)


11-24 13:30:08.752: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/0, 0, 0)


11-24 13:30:08.753: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/mnt/shell/emulated/obb, 0, 0)


11-24 13:30:08.753: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android, 0, 0)


11-24 13:30:08.754: E/cutils(2896): to chown(/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb, 0, 0)

Comment: These are the errors and warnings logcat showed

Comment: there must be more, it´s not the full logcat. Please set up a filter in eclipse to show only the logcat from Your app and limit it to error.

Comment: These are the only errors I got :\ I could've posted my code, but it connects to a bluetooth printer, and It's really nasty!
My question is: what is the proper way to show an alert without knowing the context? is it even possible? I mean if I stored the second activity's context in a pubic static variable, can I give it to the asyncTask and that's it?

Comment: AsyncTask run in background, means without blocking or effecting UI, and AlertDialog need activity as context, and Alertdialog need window to display self on it. so, you need to use interface, trigget it in interface method you can alertdialog or use run runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
  }
 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your code to show alert dialog in `runOnUiThread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // write your code here and use app context
    }
});
```